# Resizing an array from properties

Tags: c#, arrays, resize

```
private T[] Elements { get; set; }
```

If I would like to resize this array, so my first idea was to do this :

```
Array.Resize<T>(ref Elements, Capacity*2)
```

But it says I can't transform a property into an out or ref

So I did this (edited) :

```
            T[] tempContainer = new T[Capacity*2];
            Array.Copy(Elements, tempContainer, Capacity);
            Elements = tempContainer
```

But I don't think it is the most **efficient** way to resize this array.

Thank you for sharing your opinions

PS: My goal is to make a dynamic array ***without*** using lists

Answer (score 0):

You can try to handle it like this:

```
var tempContainer = Elements;
Array.Resize(ref tempContainer, Capacity*2);
Elements = tempContainer;
```

Also your current "Copy" version should fail cause both arrays are not long enough(for tempContainer always and for Elements in case if `Capacity*2` > `Elements.Length`), see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Array_System_Int64_).

Also why just not declare `Elements` as a field?

Comment: Thank you for your comment !
I am still studying in computer science and I do not know what is a field unfortunately.
Feel free to show me how I could of used a 'field', have a good day.

Comment: @master [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). Basically remove `{get; set;}`